# What should be the difference between the "license" and "legal" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have two tags that cover fairly similar ground. I'm talking about the [license](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) and [legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tags.

The two appear to fairly often be used to mean roughly the same thing; particularly, "license" seems to often be used as a more specific version of "legal". However, there are license-related questions and certainly *licensing*-related questions that are not legal questions per se. Take for example [Why do you have to be 18 to be a Volunteer Examiner?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1372/29), which asks about the US amateur radio license exam system; while the act of licensing is a legal matter, the license exam system can be discussed outside of that legal context.

**What should be the difference between [license](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) and [legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal)?** Should there be a difference, or should the two tags be merged?

Answer (score 2):

Abstractly, I think tags should be defined in a way which leads people guessing how to tag their questions to usually guess correctly. (For example, a tag should not be “X but not Y, because we have a tag for Y”, because a new questioner is likely not to know what tags exist.)

Trying to define these tags in the most straightforward way which still leaves them distinct, this is what comes to mind:

- [license](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) is for questions about *getting, having, renewing, etc.* your license, or about what you can do with a given class of license in a given jurisdiction where multiple classes exist.

  (Licenses may be a thing created by law, but, for example, so are bands, and we don't particularly want to merge [2m-band](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2m-band) with [legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal).)
- [legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) is for questions about the regulations as written and what is permitted by them.

For a example, [a question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-procedure-to-obtain-an-amateur-radio-licence-in-australia) about *how to get a license* is a [license](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) question, but not very much a [legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) question because it's not about what is *permitted* but what is *normal procedure*; asking what the law is is not to the point unless you're trying to argue with bureaucracy.

There are certainly possible questions which can reasonably be tagged with both, but not *most* of either type of question, and that's what we should be aiming for.

Comment: maybe, to make your distinction more clear, it would be good to rename "license" to "licensing".

Comment: @PhilFrost I think that would be an improvement, but a small one.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the difference between the tags should be the following.

[license](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license) covers questions related specifically to **licenses and licensing of amateur radio stations** but which are *not* answered by a reading of applicable legislation or precedent-setting legal cases. **For example,** this might cover:

- the aforementioned question
- [Would I still be a valid volunteer examiner?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1365/29) (because it is about licensing, as well as about membership in an organization)
- [What is the body of knowledge the U.S. written exams test?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/822/29) (because it is about license exam questions specifically, which insofar as I know are not legally specified)
- [What is the procedure to obtain an amateur radio licence in Australia?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/5/29) (because it is about the act of becoming licensed; obviously this might be borderline)

[legal](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) covers **questions that are specifically answered by the relevant legislation, or by precedent-setting legal cases** in case of ambiguity. This might **for example** be (because all of these should be answerable by reading the appropriate legislation, including international regulations, and/or any precedent-setting cases):

- [What radio regulations apply in International waters?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1376/29)
- [How far from earth do FCC regulations apply?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1371/29)
- [What is the permissible frequency error for US amateur radio transmissions?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1234/29)
- [Does a Canadian amateur radio operator’s certificate expire?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/1162/29)